# Score mismatch while using JPMML to evaluate a SAS produced PMML file

Tags: java, sas, pmml

I have a PMML generated from SAS Miner that I can't get properly evaluated using JPMML 1.2.6. i am getting a significant difference in scores when comparing with SAS.

Earlier,I was getting an FMTWIDTH error and resolved it using the solution mentioned in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33157862/1808924

Any ideas why I am not getting same score using JPMML?

Comment: I would contact tech support or post on communities.sas.com to get a response from SAS EM users.

Comment: I did raised this issue with tech support and posted on communities.sas.com but did not get any solution so far.

Comment: Tech support had no response? That's surprising...

Comment: SAS response is here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Mining/Score-mismatch-while-using-JPMML-to-evaluate-a-SAS-produced-PMML/m-p/235135/highlight/true#M3342

Comment: I feel there is a difference between solution and response.

Comment: I agree. I would hope they would look into it further, so I would wait to see. What was the response from tech support.